# Multiple comparison statement in bash fails - bash: [: missing `]'

Tags: command-line, bash

I need to compare a variable to multiple variables as shown below.

```
if [ [ "$SECONDS" -ne "$one" || "$SECONDS" -ne "$two" ] ]
```

This statement is giving me the error

```
[: missing `]'
```

How can I compare the value to SECONDS to both one and two. All these are integer comparison.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax of `if` for expresions in *bash* are [this refrence](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html):

**Table 7-2. Combining expressions**

```
Operation                  Effect
------------------    ------------------
[ ! EXPR ]            True if EXPR is false.
[ ( EXPR ) ]          Returns the value of EXPR. This may be used to override the normal precedence of operators.
[ EXPR1 -a EXPR2 ]    True if both EXPR1 and EXPR2 are true.
[ EXPR1 -o EXPR2 ]    True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true.
```

your if statement should be like this:

`if [ "$SECONDS" -ne "$one" -o "$SECONDS" -ne "$two" ]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `[[` keyword:

```
if [[ "$SECONDS" -ne "$one" || "$SECONDS" -ne "$two" ]];
```

Here is it's chart `help [[`:

> ```
>  EXPR1 && EXPR2   True if both EXPR1 and EXPR2 are true; else false
>  EXPR1 || EXPR2   True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true; else false
> ```

When you start your statement using `[` then space and another `[`; Bash will think that you are running a `test` (First `[`) on an other `test` (second `[`).

And before your `||` it will look for a `]`literal, can't find it and complains about it.